# Add code into html head tag from variable with Thymeleaf (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a webapp written with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. 
I need to dynamically add a custom "code" inside the HTML head tag. This custom "code" is stored inside a variable in the Spring model object. I tried many ways but none of them seem to work. These are all the ways I tested:

```
<head>
   #1 [[${headCode}]]
   #2 <div th:text="${headCode}"></div>
   #3 <span th:text="${headCode}"></span>
   #4 <div th:html="${headCode}"></div>
   #5 <div th:text="${headCode}" th:remove="tag"></div>
   #6 <div th:html="${headCode}" th:remove="tag"></div>
   #7 <span th:text="${headCode}" th:remove="tag"></span>
</head>
```

Example:
Let say we have this Spring controller which put a particular code inside the model variable "headCode":

```
@GetMapping
public String getPage(Model model){
   String headCode = "<script>
        console.log('1');
        </script>
        <script>
        console.log('2');
        </script>
        <script>
        console.log('3');
        </script>"
   model.addAttribute("headCode", headCode);
   return "page";
}
```

I would like, inside the rendered html page, to have something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   [head content]
   <script>
        console.log('1');
   </script>
   <script>
        console.log('2');
   </script>
   <script>
        console.log('3');
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   [body content]
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have a fixed code to had, I cannot hardcode it inside the head section, so I need to figure out a different way to insert it inside the head section. For instance this custom code could be the Facebook Pixel which I have to be able to change every time I need it. Any ideas?

Comment: The example code given wasn't written in the java language, but is only the output of a template engine. It's unclear, if the aim is to program an intelligent tutoring system which is teaching how Thymeleaf works on practical examples, or if the idea is to create an artificial agent which is able to convert the content of a database to a HTML page.

Comment: I don't get your point. I don't know how to dynamically put a code/script/tag inside the head tag of the html page, coming from a variable inside the Spring Model object. All the ways I tested ended up being a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with a fragment that replace the whole header element and pass any variable you need in the fragment signature.

In the official docs, there is an example of this:

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures

```
<header th:fragment="contentheader(title)" th:assert="${!#strings.isEmpty(title)}">...</header>
```

Hope this help!

Here is a working example of how to setup an endpoint, with data from the controller:

```
@GetMapping(VIEW_NAME)
  public ModelAndView viewPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(VIEW_NAME);
    modelAndView.addObject("yourDto", new YourDto());
    return modelAndView;
  }
```

Your second try in the HTML code is correct, problem should be related to the string you were passing to the view in the controller.
You should check the conditionals section of the [Thymeleaf Docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html)
Also you can download a working example their repository.

Comment: An then? How I treat variable inside the fragment? I would have the same problem then.

Comment: @Manuel Rodriguez made a point. First of all the `String headCode` won't compile, it's an invalid string asignment what you are trying there, if you want to have multiple lines use concatenation.
Also it's conceptually wrong, because html code should be placed in the template, same with scripts and css in resource files, review Thymeleaf documentation about this.
Use strings or Java data types for the model.